# Bound $\ell_2$ norm of an embedding $\sigma_i \in\mathsf{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is well-known that $\mathsf{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}) = \{\zeta_n^i \mid \gcd(i, n) = 1\}$.
Let $\sigma_i : \zeta_n\mapsto \zeta_n^i$.
I am curious about how to bound the real and imaginary parts of $\sum_{i\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times} \zeta_n^{2i}$.
Focusing on the real part for now, there is the obvious bound of $\zeta_n^{2i} \leq 1$, so the sum is at most $\varphi(n)$.
Can this bound be improved much (for general $n$)?
For example (in Landau notation) is this bound $o(\varphi(n))$, or $\Theta(\varphi(n))$?

Comment: You might find this helpful: Ramanujan's sum, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum

Comment: @SungjinKim Thanks! I think the formula entitled "von Sterneck's arithmetic function" answers my question. If you post it as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bound can actually be made exact.
The relevant quantity is an instance of [Ramunajan's sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum)

$$
c_q(n) = \sum_{a\in(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times}\exp(2\pi i \frac{a}{q}n) = \mu\left(\frac{q}{\gcd(q,n)}\right)\frac{\varphi(q)}{\varphi\left(\frac{q}{\gcd(q,n)}\right)},$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function (the second equality is with what is known as "von Sterneck's arithmetic function").
As my setting cares about $c_n(2)$, the relevant sum is
$$
\mu\left(\frac{n}{\gcd(2,n)}\right)\frac{\varphi(n)}{\varphi\left(\frac{n}{\gcd(n,2)}\right)}.
$$
From this expression, it is clear for which $n$ we can hope for a gap between $c_n(2)$ and $\varphi(n)$.